# Insert the same table widget multiple times with a param (FilamentPhp)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I need to create a widget to display the last records in a table within a category and reapeat that for every category matching certain criteria. The problem here is that I haven't found a way to do this without manually creating a widget for every category and manually inserting them in my dashboard. Any way to do this without having to create almost everything from scratch?

I was specting to be able to add a loop in the getWidgets function and dynamically add those with something like:

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $widgets[] = LastCreatedByCategoryId::make($category->id);
}
```

I don't find a way either repeat the same widget in the dashboard or to pass params to it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I am sure it will work 100% with your requirement

and this package will be helpful for what you are looking

https://github.com/rmitesh/card-stack